# Best way to read a text file by chunks in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to read a big text file and search for a string in each line, each line separated by linebreak and I need to minimize I/O and RAM

My idea is to separate the file into chunks, so I have two approachs:

1) Split the FileStream with something like this but then I risk that text lines will be cut in half and that can make things complex:

```
 using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream("InputFiles\\1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // Read the source file into a byte array.
                int numBytesToRead = 1024; // Your amount to read at a time
                byte[] bytes = new byte[numBytesToRead];

                int numBytesRead = 0;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                    int n = fsSource.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                    // Break when the end of the file is reached.
                    if (n == 0)
                        break;

                    //done something with the lines here.
                }
            }
```

2) Create an extension method to split the list of lines into smaller lists of lines and then search the word in each line but I am unsure about how this method can affect I/O and RAM!.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TValue>> Chunk<TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> values, int chunkSize)
        {
            using (var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return GetChunk(enumerator, chunkSize).ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> GetChunk<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int chunkSize)
        {
            do
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            } while (--chunkSize > 0 && enumerator.MoveNext());
        }
```

Any thoughts or other methods I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are overcomplicating things. The NET Framework has a lot of methods to choose from when you want to read a text file.

If you need to process a big text file nothing better than using the method [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) because it doesn't load all the file in memory but allows you to work line by line

As you can read from the MSDN docs

> When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   strings before the whole collection is returned;

```cs
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"InputFiles\1.txt"))
{
    // Process your line here....
}
```

Comment: I know :) but every time you enumerate this list that will cost one I/O

Comment: But your methods don't minimize RAM and I am pretty sure that I/O is buffered somewhere. And you need to solve a rather complex problem of splitted lines. So perhaps you need to test the effective efficiency of these two approaches. (I would go for ReadLines anytime though also if it is slower)

Comment: @Metalex -- Are you experiencing a bottleneck or something?  If there's no problem with your application, then don't go worrying about how many I/Os are happening.

Comment: What if my text file consists of one but veeeeery long line?

Comment: @pkuderov It depends on what you want to do with that long line. You could also use the [BinaryReader.ReadBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to read chuncks of bytes in a loop until you reach the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) method as it will read one line at a time into memory and you can perform some logic on that single line.

```
foreach(var thisLine in File.ReadLines("path"))
{
    if(thisLine.Contains("Something"))
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But that cost a lot of I/O if you have a file with millions of lines

Comment: @felix-b was a just a typo. In the link I mention `ReadLines`. I edited it. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Metalex try this method and if you see the performance is bad then you can use another technique.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, I removed my comment :)